# Add support for abbr tag

Tags: markdown, editor, feature-request

The `<abbr>` tag is useful to clarify abbreviations without hunting down external links for them.

*Migrating this from: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20090415004007/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/general/suggestions/118664-add-support-for-abbr-)*

Comment: Isn't most of geekdom `<abbr>TLA</abbr>` s? Where would it end... at the minimum, we'd need a keyboard shortcut too ;-p

Comment: Right now I try to provide wikipedia articles on the TLA. It can be useful when you have (the inevitable with only three letters) acronim clash.

Comment: `Can <abbr Title="Have">haz</abbr> <abbr Title="Please">plz</abbr>`?

Comment: See also [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user).

Comment: So...where's the `<abbr>` tag?

Comment: Would really like to just say `<abbr title="Liskov Substitution Principle">LSP</abbr>` once in a post/answer, and then just use the short form LSP elsewhere in the body of the text. Either I'd get dinged by putting LSP in the answer and people would vote down ("What's LSP??"), or type the whole thing out and people would vote down (abbreviate to LSP)--it's a no-win situation. You want to cater to as many people as you can, but not everyone has the same amount of knowledge and/or experience. SE is about sharing knowledge, and this tag would help us to do that more effectively for all audiences.

Comment: What is the gist of it? [perbert's answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/add-support-for-abbr-tag/29863#29863) demonstrates that the desired functionality is available (`title` attribute in the rendered HTML for the `a` (link) tag), but at the expense of having to use a link (internal or external)? Perhaps add a `status-` tag? Like `status-completed` if it is sufficient - *"Indicates that the report has been resolved through the implementation of a feature or the fixing of a bug."*

Comment: Or isn't it sufficient?

Comment: @fourpastmidnight If users are voting down a post for spelling out Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP) on first use and LSP on subsequent uses, maybe you need other users.  (NB: I also want the abbr tag)

Comment: @gerrit And while one could do as you did, write it out long form (provide abbreviation in parenthesis), the `<abbr title='' />` tag allows you to accomplish the same thing, and in most browsers today, providing a dashed underline and a different mouse cursor when hovering over it, to provide a tooltip for the full text of the abbreviation. _And most importantly_, the `<abbr title='' />` tag is Accessibility friendly, as screen readers can be configured to always "talk out" the abbreviation instead of saying L-S-P. (And yes, I did see that you are in favor of this proposal. :) )

Answer (score 18):

`<abbr Title="I Would Really Like To Have This">`[IWRLTHT](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/add-support-for-abbr-tag/29863#29863)`</abbr>`

Answer (score -8):

Honestly, if the abbreviation needs clarification, the external link is more useful IMO.

Comment: Don't you mean "TBH, if the abbr needs clarification, the EL is more useful IMO."?

Comment: Sites like EL&U will be using acronyms that are useful for the experts but are not part of the general lingo. Dictionaries, references and so on are often abbreviated; an abbr tag will help us teach users the new terms without requiring people to link or expand the same term dozens of times.

Comment: +1 External link + title would be good.

Comment: Hyperlinks and abbreviation tags are not mutually exclusive! I agree with @Time Traveling Bobby.