# Allow "small" and "abbr" HTML tags

Tags: feature-request, markdown, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow the <small> tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40035/allow-the-small-tag)

A long time ago [Jeff posted about allowed HTML tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/130186) and also asked what other tags do we want allowed. In the answers to that question, some tags gained lot of support, for example [`<abbr>`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13453/130186) and [`<small>`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49194/130186). Could those be enabled?

Comment: As a workaround, use `<sup>` or `<sub>` to make something smaller. Hardly noticeable when on its own paragraph.

Comment: See [Add support for abbr tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1066) and [Allow the <small> tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40035)

Comment: `<marquee>`. Nuff said

Comment: @Pekka'sReputationBordello: <blink>Marquee was at least cool!</blink>

Answer (score -4):

`abbr` shouldn't be used, instead use a link with title, [it's way more useful](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/useful) !

<sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>And I'm not sure what you want from the `small` tag, I mean, it's not really helpful, you know. The main usecase would be trolling like this one.</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>