# Add a markdown preview on community blogs

Tags: feature-request, blog-overflow, markdown-preview

One thing that's so nice about Stack Exchange is the markdown preview. You can type in code, and have it instantly rendered to make sure it looks like it should.

The [Blogoverflow community blogs](http://blogoverflow.com/) *do* support markdown, although this isn't well-known. Most people use the built-in WordPress [WYSIWWGFU](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/add-support-for-abbr-tag?lq=1) editor, which is a pain to use.

[Pagedown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) is SE's implementation of the WMD markdown editor. It's open source, and even if it weren't, SE has the source because they use it everywhere else. It's built with JavaScript, so it should be pretty easy to implement as a WordPress plugin for use on the SE blogs.

I still want a [proper integrated blogging platform](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110998/using-the-stack-engine-for-the-blog-a-long-term-idea-for-maintaining-a-healthy), but in the meantime, could a markdown preview please be added to the existing WordPress blogs? It would make blogging for Stack Exchange sites significantly easier and more enjoyable.

Comment: I [support](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-is-not-a-forum-the-role-of-niceness-on-a-qa-site/#comment-68783) [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-is-not-a-forum-the-role-of-niceness-on-a-qa-site/#comment-69327).

Comment: I second Mr. Harvey's support for this.

Comment: Anything that makes people actually want to comment makes the blogs better and makes people who write the on blogs, like me, want to write more which, I hope would make the blog better and have less run on sentences.

Comment: I was thinking this would primarily be for blog _authors_, but if we could get at least comment-flavored markdown in the comments, that'd be great too.

Comment: I support this.