# How to explain abbreviations without the disallowed <abbr> HTML tag?

Tags: support, design, markdown, editor

How can tooltips be currently added to abbreviations as long as the [<abbr> HTML tag is unsupported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/add-support-for-abbr-tag)?

Is there a Markdown equivalent or other workaround?

Answer (score 3):

[IMHO](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=IMHO), hyperlinks with titles do a decent job.

Otherwise, if you feel the need to explain an abbreviation because it's not commonly used, you should introduce it, just like you would do in an article written on paper.

Comment: See the [source code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/1a7631f6-0c3d-403a-9f53-e11f6a1093c3/view-source) of this post to see how the abbreviation/link works.

Comment: Urban Dictionary may be blocked in some cases due to NSFW content. A better website to explain common internet abbreviations is https://internetslang.com/.

Comment: Right, I'll try to remember next time. OTOH, AFAIK everybody knows what that abbreviation means :)